# ¿Como agregar datos en una fila adicional sobre una tabla en reportviewer? En C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

Por ejemplo, tengo en reportviewer en un tabla que muestro los siguientes datos, agrupados por cuenta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero resulta, que por cada cuenta(n cuentas), encima de la fila  donde está el nombre de la cuenta n°, quiero agregar una fila con un dato del saldo anterior de la cuenta.  Por ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo la query para obtener el saldo anterior, pero no se como pasárselo en la fila amarilla a la cuenta que le corresponde en reportviewer, me gustaría saber si alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo se podría hacer. No creo que se pueda hacer con grupos, o de alguna otra forma. Espero que alguien tenga alguna idea. Hasta el momento, asi genero el report viewer:

```
      public FileContentResult GetFileContentResultParametro(ReportParameter[] parametro, string nombreReporte, dynamic query, string nombreDataSource, String format, String deviceInfo, String fileDownloadName)
    {
        LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
        report.ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/" + nombreReporte);

        report.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        reportDataSource.Value = query;
        reportDataSource.Name = nombreDataSource_DataSet;
        report.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
        report.SetParameters(parametro);
        report.Refresh();


        String mimeType;
        String encoding;
        String filenameExtension;
        String[] streamIds;
        Warning[] warnings;

        FileContentResult fileContentResult = new FileContentResult(report.Render(format, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamIds, out warnings), mimeType);
        fileContentResult.FileDownloadName = Path.ChangeExtension(fileDownloadName, filenameExtension);

        return fileContentResult;
     }
```

Espero poder encontrar alguna solución. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Pero ese saldo anterior de la cuenta se podria lograr por medio de una formula de suma por cuenta

[Lesson 6: Adding Grouping and Totals (Reporting Services)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx)

lo unico que varia en tu caso es la ubicacion del valor, en lugar de ponerlo como pie del grupo lo quieres poner como cabecera del grupo siguiente

Si quieres enviarlo de forma separada quizas en el mismo datatable para la cuenta N envias repetido el valor del saldo y en la formula lo que haces es tomar el "First" el primer valor ya que para esa cuenta seran todos iguales

Comment: Hola @Leandro Tuttini, lo que pasa está en amarillo, se obtiene el saldo anterior antes de una fecha de inicio y numero de cuenta.
lo otro se lista en un intervalo de fecha de inicio a una fecha hasta.
Son query distintas, lo unico que condiciona es el numero de cuenta.

Cuando se trata de valores que trae la tabla, no tendría problema en agruparlo para hacer alguna suma, no se si me explique bien.

Comment: Existe la posibilidad de enviar un parametro, en este caso el numero de cuenta a un subreport, para que así, se vaya listando el detalle del subreport dependiendo del numero de cuenta??